# Trouble launching Samsung SDK TV Emulator

Tags: emulation, samsung-smart-tv

For some reason, my Samsung TV emulator versions 2.5.1 (2011) and version 3.5.2 (2012) work fine except for version 4.0 (2013). When I open it, it says

```
Emulator for Windows has stopped working. A program caused the program to stop working...
```

I installed the following on my machine and still doesnt seem to work:

- Visual C++ Redistributable 2005 x86 and x64
- Visual C++ Redistributable 2010 x86 and x64
- Microsoft .NET 4.5 Latest
- Java JDK (including JRE)
- Latest Direct X from
  (http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=35)

Any ideas why it shows this message? Thanks. I am on Windows 7 64 bit.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may need to install fonts for Emulator. Open `C:\Program Files (x86)\Samsung\Samsung TV SDK 4\Emulator\Emulator2013_v4\bin\`, open `*.ttf` files and select `Install`.